# Any New TextMate resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-lion, textmate

So, I just installed OSX Lion and have been trying to get TextMate setup on it (first time using TextMate). I've found all these links about installing bundles, but I can't seem to get any of them to be loaded into the program.

For instance, on pretty much all TextMate bundles, after you pull the code from github, this command is always listed:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Doing this gives me this response:

```
2011-09-16 17:32:55.276 osascript[19941:707] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
```

I'd like to find some more recent resources for TextMate so I know how to set it up for coding with Ruby on Rails 3.1 (everyone seems to talk about a screencast for Rails 2, which you have to pay for :P), so obviously most TextMate resources are far out of date. I also tried reloading the bundles within the TextMate GUI (Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Reload Bundles), but this doesn't seem to help any.

Even just some good, current resources on how to get the most out of TextMate would be great.
Thoughts?

Comment: I should add, it'd also be helpful to have a way for TextMate to understand the new asset pipeline files (style.css.scss.erb, etc.)

Comment: The widely available TextMate resources aren't out of date.  You're having some local problem, probably as a result of your upgrade to Lion.  The osascript thing in particular looks like you've got Lion-incompatible Adobe products installed (CS2 or earlier maybe?), and its preventing osascript from running altogether.

Comment: I've got CS4 installed...surely that should be compatible. What are these "widely available" resources? I've not been able to find a good list anywhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380418/how-to-improve-the-way-i-use-textmate-for-ruby-on-rails-html-css-and-javascript talks about some resources. AFAICT, some mentioned haven't been updated since 09, and aren't exactly a walkthrough on how to learn TextMate or get the proper plugins/bundles for TextMate. The Peepcode screencast mentioned is also for Rails 2, not 3 (latest Rails 2 iteration was in 09). Seems out of date to me...

Comment: I wouldn't count on any Adobe product on the Mac to be 100 % forward compatible with new OS versions. CS4 dates back to Tiger and there are lots and lots of changes above/under the hood in Lion. The applescript snippet is not necessary at all: just quit and relaunch TextMate or choose the "reload bundles" menu item if you don't want to quit. TextMate was quite disruptive for some time, there was a lot of action in the community. But the author started a v2 branch from scratch some years ago and he has been largely silent since then. With TM2 being vaporware and no new feature added to…

Comment: … the current branch, interest in TextMate has been lower and lower. That's one of the reasons you don't see many articles about TextMate after 2009. Lately, the only TM-related articles I've seen were by people explaining how to transition TO Vim or Emacs, which could be seen as a bad sign. Since 2 or 3 years a lot of editors/IDE have cherry-picked ideas from TextMate, even improving on them in places, making TextMate's appeal and uniqueness memory. In 2006/2008, TM was indeed very impressive by lack of polished contenders but now you have Coda, Espresso, Vico, Sublime Text 2…

Comment: That said, TextMate still works like a charm and most of what was written about it 3 or 4 years ago still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of well written and useful TextMate resources:

- The [TextMate: Power Editing for the Mac](http://pragprog.com/book/textmate/textmate) book
- [TextMate Setup Tutorial](http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/setup/)
- [TextMate Basics Tutorial](http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/)
- The cheatsheets [listed on TextMate's site](http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/UsefulResources)

and of course:

- [The manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/)

All of these can be found in less than 5 minutes of googling and aren't out of date at all.

The peep-code screen cast is a Rails 2 screen cast so it is obviously for Rails 2. I suggest you try their Rails 3 screen casts, there's a fair chance they are about Rails 3 and they are really easy to find on their site. And yes it's not free, but neither is TextMate.

About your bundle problem, don't bother using git or svn and that applescript trick (at least in the beginning, and your applescript system seems doomed anyway). There's a bundle called [GetBundles](https://github.com/adamsalter/GetBundles.tmbundle) that will take care of everything (listing/updating/installing outdated/new bundles) for you. Just download the .zip, expand it, rename the folder from `adamsalter-GetBundles.tmbundle-3dc27b0` to `GetBundles.tmbundle` and double-click on it for TextMate to install it automatically.

Also look around Stack Overflow and Super User: there are probably a lot of answers to your questions.

Out of curiosity, what other editor were you using before?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Textmate2, which might give you better support with Lion, and check out http://tm2tips.tumblr.com/ for some help, and ofcourse the macromates blog too.

Comment: I actually ended up going with what I think is a better alternative http://www.sublimetext.com/2 Aside from it being a similar interface and quite nice, it also allows you to use Textmate packages and has a package manager/browser.