# Getting current again with TextMate (bundles, tutorials)

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

What would be the best way to get my TextMate bundles all up to date and learn all those great keyboard shortcuts that speed development? (especially rails, html, jquery, blogging)

I have circa 2008 textmate books; looking for up to date tutorials, bundles etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451079/any-new-textmate-resources) 3 questions below.

In short: whatever tutorials/books/resources you had in 2008 still apply because TextMate hasn't evolved since then and the right way to have up to date bundles is to use the [GetBundles](https://github.com/adamsalter/GetBundles.tmbundle) bundle.